# Find all values in column and replace with a transformed value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, transform

I have a dataframe created from a large csv file. One of the columns is "Bytes", but some of the values are actually Megabytes in the form of '1.6 M' in instead of '1600000'.  I can find the bad values, split the out and do the calculation on the 1.6 as seen below.

But, how do I save the new value back to overwrite the existing value in that row of the 'Bytes' column?

```
for i in df1.Bytes:
    if "M" in str(i):
        i = int(float(i.split()[0]) * 1000000)
        
    else:
        i = int(i)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorize your operations using a mapping dict to replace your factors ('M', 'K', etc):

```
factors = {'M': 100000, 'K': 1000}

df['Bytes2'] = (df['Bytes'].str.split(' ', expand=True).fillna(1)
                           .replace(factors).astype(float)
                           .pipe(lambda x: x[0] * x[1]))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Bytes    Bytes2
0   1.6 M  160000.0
1  378764  378764.0
2   3.7 K    3700.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `str.replace` method:

```
factors = {'M': 'e6', 'K': 'e3'}

df['Byte2'] = df.Byte.str.replace(" *(M|K)",
                      lambda x: factors.get(x[1]), regex = True).astype(float)

df
Out[343]: 
     Byte       Byte2
0    16 M  16000000.0
1  378764    378764.0
2   3.7 K      3700.0
3      4K      4000.0
```